# rsyslog to forward json payload to kafka using an api key+secret

Tags: logging, apache-kafka, rsyslog

I would like to forward a json payload via rsyslog to a cloud hosted apache kafka instance using an api key+secret for authentication. I don't see any authentication parameters for the omkafka module documented. What would be the best approach to do this?

Would the `omfwd` module be an alternative using the `streamDriver` parameters? If yes, how would I be able to set a `topic` parameter just like on the `omkafka` module?

**/etc/rsyslog.d/kafka.conf**

```
module(load="omkafka")

template(name="jsonFormat" type="list") {
    constant(value="{")
        constant(outname="data" value="myData" format="jsonf")
    constant(value="}")
}

action(type="omkafka" broker=["example.domain.com:9092"] topic="my.topic.added" template="jsonFormat")
```

**EDIT:**

Looks like parameter confParam could be used. However, when filling it with authentication details, rsyslog throws an error.
`"errcode": -192, "errmsg": "Local: Message timed out"`

```
action(
    type="omkafka"
    broker=["example.domain.com:9092"]
    topic="my.topic.added"
    template="jsonFormat"
    key="my_key"
    partitions.auto="on"
    confParam=[
        "sasl.mechanisms=PLAIN",
        "sasl.username=<api_key>",
        "sasl.password=<api_secret>",
        "security.protocol=sasl_plaintext"
    ]
    errorFile="/var/log/rsyslog/kafka-error.log"
)
```